# Solr search Query with white spaces

Tags: solr

I have in my xml Schema a node like this:

```
<str name="name">Samsung galaxy S4</str>
```

and I want that Solr gives a result when I search for example only "Samsung galaxy"

How can I write the Query to search with the white spaces?

UPDATE:
That's the example of my nodes:

```
  <doc>
    <str name="id">16_1</str>
    <str name="product_id">16</str>
    <str name="store_id">1</str>
    <str name="name">Samsung galaxy S4</str>
    <str name="short_description">The words "entry level" no longer mean "low-end," especially when it comes to the Nokia 2610. Offering advanced media and calling features without breaking the bank</str>
    <str name="sku">n2610</str>
    <str name="manufacturer">Nein</str>
    <long name="_version_">1438897917491412992</long></doc>
  <doc>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: any documents you have in solr. you may have this document without "S4".

Comment: I haven't understand your comment

Comment: Can you have multiple documents in solr?

Comment: yes, there is multiple documents having the sane "name", but always a unic "id"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have defined datatype of `name` field as `string`. In case of `string` datatype, value(Samsung Galaxy S4) is not tokenized so you can't search for a partial value.

Change the datatype to some tokenized type, ex. `text_en`

After changing the datatype you can query normally as:

`/select/?q=name:"Samsung Galaxy"`

Note that after changing type to `text_en`, you will also get results when you search only for `Samsung`

Comment: I have tried with:
`<field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />` and also
`<field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />` but it could not match a document containing "Samsung Galaxy"

Comment: Are you sure that you have re-indexed documents after changing the datatype? Unless you reindex, the field will not be tokenized.

Comment: Yes, I have always deleted the index and created a new one, but always, I see in logs that Solr replace the white spaces with "+" like this : `/select params={indent=true&q=name:"Samsung+Galaxy"&_=1372328011401&wt=xml} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0` ; ist that false ?